# Text search capabilities?

Tags: text, full-text-search

We have a framework that has hundreds of XML files/text files/resources that decide the behavior of the system.(the huge number is because of legacy reasons)

Other teams use this framework and build different products on top of it.

To build a product using the framework, typically means configuring the XML files in various different ways.

The issue the consumers of our platform face, is that they are not sure what files are needed, what files are not and what should be tweaked and what should not be.

In other words I think what they lack is good documentation. (We do have a documents but they describe individual components in the system but miss out on the big picture and do not demonstrate a system work flow)

So what I was thinking is to come up with a semantic text based search engine, that indexes these files and presents them in a intuitive manner.

For example if the consumer of our platform wants to know "How do I accomplish blah", then the search engine should point out the steps involved in accomplishing blah.

Is this a good idea? If so, what text based searching engines can we use. (Lucene is the only thing I know of)

Comment: "How do I accomplish blah", then the search engine should point out the steps involved in accomplishing blah.... If you can achieve this, you could probably give up your existing line of work and concentrate on putting google out of business

Comment: :) Well my goals are a bit more modest . The total size of the all the configuration files combined is approximately 100Mb. But what is missing currently is linking between the files in a meaningful way and presenting it in a understandable way.

Comment: You could look into using Sphinx.  I've not used it personally, but have heard very high praises.